# Can I use a Docker container for InfluxDB?

Tags: database, docker, device, influxdb

I have two devices `/dev/sda/` and `/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV`. The first device is used for my software and the second is used for my storage. I need to centralize a database (i.e. InfluxDB). What is the best way to build a centralized database? A dedicated database Docker container (locally)? If so, how can I interact with the Docker container?

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        6.7G  2.7M  6.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  151G  123G   21G  86% /
tmpfs                         34G   94M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    705M  373M  282M  57% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV    3.5T  601G  2.7T  18% /HFT
tmpfs                        6.7G   16K  6.7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        6.7G  180K  6.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private      151G  123G   21G  86% /home/infinity
```

Comment: Would you expand on what you mean by "centralise" in this context? In plain English terms, to centralise something means to take several cases of something (e.g. a database server) and merge them together (perhaps to make them easier to maintain). However, I am not sure how that relates to the problem you have.

Comment: There are plenty of ways to interact with a Docker container, but this part of your question needs narrowing down. What do you want to happen when you interact with the container?